# Inheriting a hash table class to use different hash function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to implement a Hash Table with a Probing Sequence and inherit another Hash Table from it that is exactly the same but uses different hash functions.

Here, `ProbeSequenceHashTable` is the fully implemented parent class with hash function h, and I am trying to implement `DoubleHashingHashTable` that inherits from `ProbeSequenceHashTable` but uses a new hash function with the same name, `h`, that uses `h0` and `h1`. I am hoping that the functions implemented in the parent class work in the same way but use the new hash functions in the derived class. I am not sure how to achieve this, without maybe passing the hash functions as parameters to the methods. I also tried using `(*this).h` instead of just `h`.

```
vector <int> primes = {11,23,47,97,197,397,797,1597,3203,6421};

class ProbeSequenceHashTable {
    private:
        int h(int k) {
            cout << "using old hash function" << endl;
            return (k % M);
        }
        int h(int k, int i) {
            return ((h(k) + i) % M);
        }
    protected:
        vector <int> T;
        int M;
    public:
        ProbeSequenceHashTable(int M) : M{M}, T{vector <int> (M, -2)} {}
        // -1 : deleted
        // -2 : NIL
        pair <bool, int> insert(int k) {
            int probes = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                probes++;
                int p = h(k, i);
                if (T[p] == -1 || T[p] == -2) {
                    T[p] = k;
                    return make_pair(true, probes);
                }
            }
            return make_pair(false, probes);
        }
        pair <int, int> search(int k) {
            int probes = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                probes++;
                int p = h(k, i);
                if (T[p] == -2) {
                    return make_pair(-1, probes);
                }
                else if (T[p] == k) {
                    return make_pair(p, probes);
                }
            }
            return make_pair(-1, probes);
        }
        int remove(int k) {
            pair <int, int> res = search(k);
            int i = res.first;
            int probes = res.second;
            T[i] = -1;
            return probes;
        }
        int rehash() {
            for (int p : primes) {
                if (p > 2 * M) {
                    int M0 = M;
                    M = p;
                    vector <int> T0 = T;
                    T = vector <int> (M, -2);
                    for (int i = 0; i < M0; i++) {
                        if (T0[i] >= 0) {
                            insert(T0[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return M;
                }
            }
            cerr << "ERROR: Size too large" << endl;
            throw runtime_error("ERROR: Size too large");
        }
        int getSize() {
            return M;
        }
};

class DoubleHashingHashTable : public ProbeSequenceHashTable {
    private:
        int h0(int k) {
            return (k % M);
        }
        int h1(int k) {
            return 1 + floor((M - 1) * ((0.618 * k) - floor(0.618 * k)));
        }
        int h(int k, int i) {
            cout << "using new hash function" << endl;
            return (h0(k) + i * h1(k)) % M;
        }
    public:
        DoubleHashingHashTable(int M) : ProbeSequenceHashTable{M} {}
};
```

Comment: `h`, `this->h` and the unnecessarily verbose `(*this).h` should all produce the same results so long as you do not have some local variable `h` shadowing that property. Use `h` unless you have extenuating circumstances, then `this->h` as a back-up plan. `(*this).h` looks completely misguided.

Comment: Those hash functions are private and non-virtual. You *can't* override them in any way that will be effective. Even if you could, this is a poor use of inheritance. The hash function should be overloaded at the top-level or passed in as a (possibly templated) argument.